# Why is this character suddenly so antagonistic?

Tags: alice-in-borderland

**Warning: This question contains massive spoilers about Alice in Borderland: Season 2. If you have not watched this season to the end yet, read on your own risk.**

At the beginning of episode 2x07, Arisu and Chishiya meet again after having been separated earlier in the season. They seem to start a normal conversation, but Niragi interrupts by shooting at Chishiya, essentially proposing that the three shoot at each other just "for fun".

Chishiya then picks up a gun and thinks it's not a bad idea, telling Arisu that "he's got a bone to pick with [Chishiya]" and that they "can settle things once and for all". (Arisu seems confused by that, asking "What the hell are you talking about?") It then seems that not only Niragi, but also Chishiya start shooting at Arisu.

It takes Arisu's motivational speech to make both Niragi and Chishiya relax and lower their weapons. (Notwithstanding what happens afterward once Usagi surprisingly enters the scene.)

Now, we know that Niragi has violent and sadistic tendencies, and his behaviour does not surprise me. However: **What is going on with Chishiya here? Why does he suddenly become so antagonistic toward Arisu that he'd almost shoot him? What is that (proverbial, of course) bone they allegedly have to pick?**

Answer (score 1):

Chishiya has been on a dark arc in the second series of Alice in Borderland.

He showed signs of this in the first series with his cynical attitude towards the survival of others in the Tag game and his abandonment of Arisu and Usagi to probable torture/rape during the Beach political infighting.

However, he steps his immorality up a gear in the second series with his mocking murder of an innocent team mate during the Jack of Hearts game and his abandonment of the Jack to torture by a pair of ambitious psychopaths.

Given this behaviour, and the indications that he might choose to stay in the Borderland world, he might have seen the shootout as a chance to weed out other potential Borderland challengers/citizen candidates. More charitably he might have been expecting to team up with Arisu to rid them both of the danger of Niragi (who he actively feuds with in the first series).